# How can I assert that my List implementation acts the same way as all the Lists in JDK?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, junit, linked-list

I am developing a **List** implementation and I would love to put it to exactly same tests as JDK's **ArrayList** and **LinkedList**.

Where can I find JDK's tests for the two?

Also, I am aware about Apache Commons Collection's **TreeList** and all extensive testing it is going through, yet ain't sure whether I can trust it.

Comment: I am not positive, but wouldn't the unit tests be available in the Java source?

Comment: The Answer to linked question should allow you to find what you are looking for.  I didn't check to see if the OpenJDK list unit tests are worthwhile. YMMV.